# How to convert tar.gz file to zip using Python only?

Tags: python, zip, tar

Does anybody has any code for converting tar.gz file into zip using only Python code? I have been facing many issues with tar.gz as mentioned in the [How can I read tar.gz file using pandas read_csv with gzip compression option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263929/how-can-i-read-tar-gz-file-using-pandas-read-csv-with-gzip-compression-option)

Comment: It must be a problem in the csv not the tar.gz

Comment: I wish that was true, but I tried with three different tar.gz files.

Comment: @Geet - Do you have feedback on answers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to use the [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) module, with mode `'r|gz'` for reading.
Then use [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#module-zipfile) for writing.

```
import tarfile, zipfile
tarf = tarfile.open( name='mytar.tar.gz', mode='r|gz' )
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile( file='myzip.zip', mode='a', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED )
for m in tarf:
    f = tarf.extractfile( m )
    fl = f.read()
    fn = m.name
    zipf.writestr( fn, fl )
tarf.close()
zipf.close()
```

You can use `is_tarfile()` to check for a valid tar file.

Perhaps you could also use [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#archiving-operations), but I think it cannot work on memory.

PS: From the brief testing that I performed, you may have issues with members `m` which are directories.
If so, you may have to use `is_dir()`, or even first get the info on each tar file member with `tarf.getmembers()`, and the open the `tar.gz` file for transferring to `zip`, since you cannot do it after `tarf.getmembers()` (you cannot seek backwards).

Comment: Really appreciate your help, here.I need just one more step. I changed zipf = ZipFile.open to zipf = zipfile.ZipFile.open. Now, it says "NameError: name 'ZIP_DEFLATED' is not defined"

Comment: @Geet - I have now tested the code and fixed it. Please let me know if it suits you. Beware of the issue with directories that I mention!

Comment: doesn't seem to work on Python 3? I get  `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: This is an old Q&A, I am not certain, but I guess it should work under python3 (and I possibly tested using python3). The error likely comes from `fl = f.read()`. Please check you are correctly opening a tar file, which has only files (to begin with).

Comment: this doesn't work with Python 3.7. Giving me ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'``` error in the command ```fl = f.read()```. Any solution for Python 3.7?

Comment: @Bogota - Apparently your  `f` is of `NoneType`. Try checking why that is the return value obtained from `tarf.extractfile( m )`.
Yours seems the same issue as mu7z had.

Answer (score 1):

This just fixes a couple of tiny issues from the above answer, makes sure the mtime is preserved and makes sure compression is happening on all the files. All credit to the above for the simple answer.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import sys
from tarfile import open
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZIP_DEFLATED, ZipInfo

compresslevel = 9
compression = ZIP_DEFLATED

with open(name=sys.argv[1], mode='r|gz') as tarf:
    with ZipFile(file=sys.argv[2], mode='w', compression=compression, compresslevel=compresslevel) as zipf:
        for m in tarf:
            mtime = datetime.fromtimestamp(m.mtime)
            print(f'{mtime} - {m.name}')
            zinfo: ZipInfo = ZipInfo(
                filename=m.name,
                date_time=(mtime.year, mtime.month, mtime.day, mtime.hour, mtime.minute, mtime.second)
            )
            if not m.isfile():
                # for directories and other types
                continue
            f = tarf.extractfile(m)
            fl = f.read()
            zipf.writestr(zinfo, fl, compress_type=compression, compresslevel=compresslevel)

print('done.')
```