# Is there any command on Linux to convert .tar.gz files to .zip?

Tags: linux, zip, tar

I've received files in .tar.gz type but the application I'm using only accepts .zip files. I need an easy way of converting .tar.gz files to .zip without loosing any of the data.

Does renaming to .zip will work? I've tried it but when I click on the file it's showing it as a invalid file.

Any thoughts or inputs for this?

Comment: that is two different archive formats, renaming wouldn't help.

Comment: write a script that unpacks the tar file and then packs everything back up as a zip file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert tar.gz to zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301885/convert-tar-gz-to-zip)

Comment: Thanks. I'll post in relevant forums now onwards.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<del>You can probably convert your archive `foo.tar.gz` into a zipped archive `foo.zip` with a command similar to this one:</del>

<del>`tar xzOf foo.tar.gz | zip foo.zip $(tar tf foo.tar.gz)`</del>

<del>In details: `tar xzOf foo.tar.gz` extracts (`x`) the gzipped (`z`) archive to standard output (`O`). Here `f` is used to provide the input file name.</del>

<del>Standard input is piped into `zip`, whose first argument is the name of the zipped file to produce. The following argument is the list of the files to compress, that we can obtain directly from `tar` with the `t` command, run on the initial `.tar.gz` file.</del>

**Edit:** I thought the above one-liner could be used to easily convert a tar archive into a zip file. Reading again the command one year later or so, it turns out it looks badly broken: it just takes the names of the files from the tar archive, and zip from the original files (non-compressed), if they are still on the disk. I don't see how to produce a simple one-liner, since you apparently cannot provide both the name and the contents of the file to `zip` on the command line (see also [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019603/how-do-you-specify-filenames-within-a-zip-when-creating-it-on-the-command-line-f)).

So we probably need two steps to do this: first uncompress from the tar archive, then compress again. Something like:

```
tar xzf foo.tar.gz && zip foo.zip $(tar tf foo.tar.gz)
```

We can also add a third part to remove the temporarily decompressed files: `&& rm -r -- $(tar tf foo.tar.gz)`, but be cautious and make sure this does not erase stuff you want to keep.

For more details, have a look at the manual pages of `zip` and `tar` utilities.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked for me.

Comment: This is neat, but looks like it doesn't work for files in the top-level directory, those are missing in the zip file.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Berdir. Actually I'm reading my answer again, and I think the whole command is broken. It looks like `zip` is taking the file names to compress from `$(tar tf foo.tar.gz)`, but does not take the contents of those files from `tar` output (it loads them from the uncompressed files again). Does this even work if the original files have been moved or removed?

Comment: Good point, that might actually be the reason for the behavior I saw, the folder did exist in the local folder while the other two files did not. I ended up doing it manually in two steps, first decompress in a temporary folder and then zipping it

Comment: If you're dealing with an archive containing lots of files (80k+), you may hit `argument list too long` error. The quick solution is to make `zip` read list of files from stdin like this: `tar tf foo.tar.gz | zip -@rj foo.zip`

Comment: How to make it work if my source archive is in a different directory like that: zip files/test.zip $(tar tf files/test.gz)

Comment: Seems the z was missing from the second tar command, and failed with ```tar: Refusing to read archive contents from terminal (missing -f option?)
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

zip error: Nothing to do!```

Worked for me with `tar xzf foo.tar.gz && zip foo.zip $(tar tfz foo.tar.gz)`

Comment: @GuillaumeBerche OK, I don't know about the missing `z`, it works well without it in my case (just re-tested it, using GNU tar 1.34). But thanks for reporting anyway!