# How to make this command work from parent directory zip files/test.zip $(tar tf files/test.gz)

Tags: shell, command-line, zip, tar

I've this command:

```
zip files/test.zip $(tar tf files/test.gz)
```

But it doesn't work because everything from $(tar tf files/test.gz) are in files/
So zip can't find it.
It works perfectly if I change directory to files and exec this one:

```
zip test.zip $(tar tf test.gz)
```

But I need to make it work from parent directory.

My full command is:

```
tar xzf files/test.tar.gz && zip files/test.zip $(tar tf files/test.tar.gz) && rm -r -- $(tar tf files/test.tar.gz)
```

From [Is there any command on Linux to convert .tar.gz files to .zip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787941/is-there-any-command-on-linux-to-convert-tar-gz-files-to-zip?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Thank you

Comment: why can't you pushd, enter the `files` execute the cmd, then popd? what is your real problem? you want to zip all files in the tar? or you want to zip files with same filenames in tar?

Comment: @Kent I want to convert my tar.gz to zip

Answer (score 0):

I would make a little script for that. If you have many tgz files to handle, you can apply a loop on it.

```
#!/bin/bash
TMP=/a/tmp/directory
TARGET=/dir/to/your/files
mkdir -p $TMP   
cd $TMP
tar -C $TMP -xzf $TARGET/your.tar.gz && zip $TARGET/your.zip *  
rm -rf $TMP
```

Comment: This will add the temp directory inside zip file. -j argument doesn't work here because I only want to remove the first directory if there is some more